# AccessToken matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth, django-rest-framework

I am creating a an API for registering user based on oauth token. My app has functionality like registration and login, adding restaurant etc. I created user registration part but i get error while login. I want login based on token.

I have used django-oauth-toolkit for this and DRF.

What i have done is

**Login based on token**

```
class UserCreateAPI(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

class UserLoginAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=request.POST.get('access_token'), expires__gt=timezone.now()) # error is shown here
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**For creating user with a token**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        confirm_password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User(
                username = username,
                first_name = first_name,
                last_name = last_name,
                email = email
            )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        if user_obj:
            expire_seconds = oauth2_settings.user_settings['ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS']
            scopes = oauth2_settings.user_settings['SCOPES']

            application = Application.objects.get(name="Foodie")
            expires = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=expire_seconds)
            access_token = AccessToken.objects.create(user=user_obj, 
                                                    application=application,
                                                    token = generate_token(),
                                                    expires=expires, 
                                                    scope=scopes)
        return validated_data


class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)
    username = CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password',
            # 'token',

        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password":
                            {"write_only": True}
                            }
```

I have excluded fields part and validation part for shortening the code

Am i doing the right way?

Comment: Make sure that the access token is registered inside the database and that it is not yet expired (use./manage.py shell).

Comment: It is registered in the databse. I will check the expiry period.

Comment: My expiry second is 'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 36000000. So i dont think it will expire. How to check if it is expired or not?

Comment: print request.POST.get('access_token') just before the instruction AccessToken.objects.get(...) and check its value

Comment: I get None in terminal.

Comment: But the token has been created. You can see on the UserCreateSerializer. Why i am getting token None?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use request.data instead of request.post in order to get the access_token(http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/):

```
access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token=request.data.get('access_token'), expires__gt=timezone.now())
```

use request.DATA if you are using the Version-2 of DRF. request.data is for version-3

============UPDATE========================================
You should implement your own login procedure or modify the existing one; because when user log in, the access_token is not actually sent to the server.

The login procedure should look like this :

1. When the user enter his login and password, your app should send a post request to 127.0.0.1:8000/o/token asking for the token. The request should contains the username, password, client_id and client_secret.
2. the server then receives the credentials and if they are valid it returns the access_token.
3. The rest of the time you should query the server using that token.

But, i'm not sure that it is what you are actually doing.

Comment: I still get None using request.data as i am using version 3 of DRF.

Comment: Do you mean print (request.data)?

Comment: request.data does not have access_token key. <QueryDict: {'username': ['admin'], 'password': ['admin123'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bKmeI36duqDbtEWXFn1PZ6WDGufXAfqgUAJEABFEJhZR2MjA7TJBRMC5ro3x']}>

Comment: I meant the request made from the client side. How do send the token ?

Comment: $ curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin123" -u"clientsecretkey" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
This gives me {"error": "invalid_client"}. In clientsecretkey i put clientsecretkey from admin applications

Comment: client_id and client_secret are missing in your request.

Comment: Can you provide me a syntax? I have seen most have done the way i have done and theirs is working.

Comment: i did curl -X POST -d'username=sanskars&password=sanskar123&grant_type=password&client_id=Ono1Tn2pzgVgyoAJY5Txv99iRxRkPocAq0mW1'-u"AEYBoj5twSOJ1UJ8PEeoM7RkuKhoLEo4TMWAchMpI9qVa4ZZb9NoFdFkpKTgGIYyU75AlRwddkM6CO1mux1tKe68MbfjEuBuZun293M84wGHwDARy3mamTLAbeg3Z" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/ but no avail

Comment: with these command

curl -X POST -d "client_id=Ono1Tn2pzgVgyoAJxJkY5Txv99iRxRkPocAq0mW1&client_secret=AEYBoj5twSOJ1UJ8PEeoM7Rkur06KhoLEo4TMWAchMpI9qVa4ZZb9NoFdFkpKTgGIYyU75AlRwddkM6CO1mux1tKe68MbfjEuBuZun293M84wGHwDARy3mamTLAbeg3Z&grant_type=password&username=sanskars&password=tushant123" http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/

i got 

{"access_token": "pNJU6GXdarsEVf3WdvaVOzglHyNUdt", "scope": "read", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000000, "refresh_token": "dOClHTLoAwjKYnnlSdcgqVmAtRaOjt"}

Comment: But it is still throwing an error of  DoesNotExist at /api/restaurant/login/
AccessToken matching query does not exist.

Comment: hummm!!! can you print your login method on the frontend side. I am suspecting that you do not actually send the token to the server side.

Comment: <QueryDict: {'username': ['admin'], 'password': ['admin123'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['bKmeI36duqDbtEWXFn1PZ6WDGufXAfqgUAJEABFEJhZR2MjA7TJBRMC5ro‌​3x']}> "access_token" does not appear inside this dic.

Comment: UserLoginAPI is my login method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122670/discussion-between-learner-and-florex).